# Width Specify with printf to generate a clean outlook

Tags: shell

I have written a small snippet for nslookup on multiple hosts.., now i want to use the printf to specify the width which i am failing to implement..

What i want is to 18 char long space after any $ADDR or say Server name to have a clean display.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
while read ADDR
do
RESULT=`nslookup ${ADDR}`
if [  $? != 0 ]; then
printf "%-28s\n"  "Srever ${ADDR} Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate"
#echo "Server ${ADDR}           Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate" | tee -a mylookup.log
else
printf "%-28s\n"  "Srever ${ADDR} Namelookup Success"
#echo "Server ${ADDR}           Namelookup Success" | tee -a mylookup.log
fi
done < /home/karn/host1.txt
```

## CURRENT SCRIPT RESULT:

```
Srever koslfarm03.pmkrr.com Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm04.pmkrr.com Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm05.pmkrr.com Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm08.pmkrr.com Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm10 Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm11 Namelookup Success
```

EXPECTED SCRIPT RESULT Should be as Below:

```
Srever koslfarm03.pmkrr.com        Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm04.pmkrr.com        Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm05.pmkrr.com        Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm08.pmkrr.com        Namelookup Success
Srever koslfarm10 Namelookup       Success
Srever koslfarm11 Namelookup       Success
```

Comment: Note you can always pipe to `column -t`.

Comment: @fedorqui using `column -t` will delimit space to all strings like....

`Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate`  <- in this every string will be have spece.

Comment: Could you update and show what is the *expected* output?

Comment: @fedorqui ... updated.

Comment: i don't see the 18 char long space in the expected results. (which is rather strange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to create a column of specified width, use something like this:

```
printf 'Server %-28sNamelookup %s\n' "$ADDR" "$result"
```

Full script:

```
awk NF /home/karn/host1.txt | while read -r ADDR; do
  nslookup "$ADDR" >/dev/null

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    result="Success"
  else
    result="Failed, please investigate"
  fi

  printf 'Server %-28sNamelookup %s\n' "$ADDR" "$result"
done
```

Note, `awk NF` removes blank lines. Alternatively, you can do this within the
loop:

```
ADDR="${ADDR// /}"
[ -z "$ADDR" ] && continue
```

Here we remove spaces from `$ADDR`, then check if the string is empty. If it's empty, we skip the iteration.

Comment: Its gives the eror `/usr/bin/nslookup: '' is not a legal name (unexpected end of input)`  and for every nslookup it gives `Namelookup $result`

Comment: The "full script" here is missing the input redirection for the loop and tries to expand `$result` in a single-quoted string.

Comment: @EtanReisner ... Can you backfill that missing part please.

Comment: It missed the ` < /home/karn/host1.txt` bit from your initial script. And to fix the `printf` just move `$result` to outside the single quoted string, add a format specifier for it in the string and then add `$result` as an argument after `$ADDR`.

Comment: That fixed the redirection. It still missed `$results` in the single quoted string.

Comment: @EtanReisner, indeed. Fixed.

Comment: It would have been better to keep the single quotes and pull `$result` out to an argument like `$ADDR` and like I said in my previous comment.

Comment: I have fixed the quotes .. everything runs good but still there is  a error at the end of the script..


`nslookup: '' is not a legal name (unexpected end of input)
Server                             Namelookup Failed, please investigate`

Comment: May be i am not expert to the scripting as just trying to learn it...would be great if you can edit your suggested code.

Comment: @Karn, because of blank lines in the source file. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Karn, added pure Bash check if `$ADDR` is empty.

Comment: @Ruslan .. You make my day, Great catch indeed.. that's the reason.

Comment: Can this be added for the add on like..

`  printf 'Server Name                   Server Status\n'`

 ` printf '===========================================\n'`

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand the expected result logic, but the following:

```
fakensl() { return $(($RANDOM % 2)); }
while read -r host
do
    result=$(fakensl "$host" && echo "Namelookup Success" || echo "Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate")
    printf "%-28.28s%s\n" "$host" "$result"
done < <(seq -f 'ahost%g.example.com' 5 ; seq -f 'bhost%g' 5 )
```

will print something like:

```
ahost1.example.com          Namelookup Success
ahost2.example.com          Namelookup Success
ahost3.example.com          Namelookup Success
ahost4.example.com          Namelookup Success
ahost5.example.com          Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate
bhost1                      Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate
bhost2                      Namelookup Success
bhost3                      Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate
bhost4                      Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate
bhost5                      Namelookup Failed, Please Investigate
```

Answer (score 3):

You have one format specifier, and one string. This will result in one solid output string.

```
$ printf '%-10s %10s\n' "foo" "bar"
foo               bar
```